# How to use find for finding and deleting corrupted files?

Tags: find, corruption

After I recovered a huge amount of files with Photorec and TestDisk, I tried opening some files and most cannot be opened, for which I assume they're just partially recovered. That part of my HD was encrypted.

I'd like to sort them out (estimated some hundreds or thousands I recovered) with `find` and delete them. (Don't need to be shredded, but would be nice).

Is it something like `find /home/user/ \! -readable -exec rm -i {} \;`?

Comment: Encryption on the block device level (e.g. LUKS) should not make a difference to restoring, just encryption on file level (e.g. encryptfs). I guess by "readable" you mean "can be used by the application". But how is that detected? I guess you need the application and check its exit code. It does not make sense to check just on the file system permission level.

Comment: `-readable` only checks whether you have *permission* to read the file

Answer (score 1):

You can run `file` on on the files and see if this shows the expected type. This only looks at the first few bytes of a file, but at least you might be able sort out some of the files that are corrupted in the first block.

E.g.

```
file `find /home/user -type f | grep jpg` | sed -e/JPEG/d
```

will show you at least some of the files that are corrupted